# Rejecting extra url parameters from params hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am building an API using rails that can take quite a few parameters. Ideally, if the user includes an extra, unnecessary paramater in the request by accident which does not make the request ambiguous I would like to process it as normal. This obviously prevents me from simply writing

```
  ApiRequest.new(params)
```

since an UnknownAttributeError will be thrown if there is anything extra in the params hash. Is there a simple way of rejecting the extra attributes or will I have to write a method to manually validate the request before creating a new object. Also, would this be considered bad practise for an API, should I be responding with HTTP 400 if this occurs?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: How do you decide what attributes are 'extra'?

Comment: By extra I just mean anything that isn't in ActiveRecord or defined as an attribute in the model. Basically any parameter which isn't defined for that particular API action.

Comment: You can get all model attributes by calling `YourModel.attributes`. Then you can filter out any extra parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion Sergio, I ended up adding the following initialize method in my ApiRequest class which allows me to mass assign regardless of what is in the hash. If anyone uses this just make sure you ensure attributes are attr_protected if they need to be.

```
def initialize(params)
    params.delete_if {|k| !self.respond_to? "#{k}="}
    super
end
```